# Application buggy after installing IE 8.0

Tags: asp.net

The HRIS app in my company is a asp.net web application which started showing bugs after IE 8.0 was rolled out on our company intranet. Few people open multiple instances of the app with different credentials, now since IE 8.0 has this session sharing feature on different browser windows, the sessions in both windows become the same but the data rendered on controls of the page is different and that results in incosistent data going into the database.

The application is huge and has a userbase of more than 5000. Is there any way other than changing the session to cookieless. One approach could be to restrict only one instance of the app on a mchine at a time. But I am not able to find a way to implement this. Looking for a solution which would have minimum impact.

Answer (score 0):

The meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">` forces IE8 to act like IE 7 . I'm not sure if that extends as far as session handling, but it's easy to implement at least and so seems worth a try.